# Semaphore/Critial section implementation

Tags: semaphore, critical-section

I'm trying to learn about mutex, semaphores and critical sections and I'm uncertain about some things with semaphores. Is a semaphore the same as a critical section? The definition of how to use semaphores from semaphore.h states the use is:

```
sem_t m;
sem_init(&m, 0, X); // initialize semaphore to X; what should X be?

sem_wait(&m);
// critical section here
sem_post(&m);
```

So my question is really is the "// critical section here" actually a critical section?

Comment: Semaphore is the screwdriver that lets you build additional synchronization constructs.  Like a mutex or critical section.  The latter needs a binary semaphore, X=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semaphores are tools used to *protect* critical sections: to insure that only one CS is being executed at a time.

In you example, the first process to execute `sem_wait(&m)` gets to execute its copy of the critical section; any other process that tries to execute its correspoinding `sem_wait` will be blocked, until out first process finishes its CS by executing `sem_post`.  AT that point, some other call to `sem_wait` will return, starting the process again.

Comment: Okay so to be sure, if I have a function which uses std::cout, if I place sem_wait() and sem_post() around the cout, will it become a critical section?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I get it a bit more now

Comment: You have the causality backwards: a section of code is a critical section *because*  it needs to be executed single-threaded, and semaphores are a way to implement that.  Wrapping some code in semaphore calls causes it to be run single-threaded, but doesn't make it necessary to do so.

Comment: No I think I get it, its because I want to make my cout function a critical section, because two threads are using it simultaneously, so I can implement the critical section by surrounding the cout with sem_wait and sem_post. Right?

Comment: That's more like it!